# Is there a security vulnerability to permit all CORS origins if the request origin matches a pattern?

Tags: csrf

Originally asked at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29526990/is-there-a-security-vulnerability-to-permit-all-cors-origins-if-the-request-orig

We had a requirement to permit cross-origin requests provided that the origin was part of the corporate domain. While this question is not C# or Web API specific, the snippets below demonstrate our strategy.

We have a collection of regular expressions defining permitted origins:

```
    private static readonly Regex[] AllowedOriginPatterns = new[]
    {
        new Regex(@"https?://\w[\w\-\.]*\.company.com",
                  RegexOptions.Compiled | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)
    };
```

Later, in our `ICorsPolicyProvider` attribute, we test the origin. If the origin matches any pattern, we add the origin to the set of allowed origins:

```
    var requestOrigin = request.GetCorsRequestContext().Origin;
    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(requestOrigin) &&
        AllowedOriginPatterns.Any(pattern => pattern.IsMatch(requestOrigin)))
    {
        policy.Origins.Add(requestOrigin);
    }
```

The perk of this approach is that we can support a large and flexible set of authorized origins, and restrict unauthorized origins, all without placing hundreds of origins in our headers.

We have an issue with HTTP header rewriting on the part of our reverse proxy. Under some circumstances, the reverse proxy replaces the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` value with the host. Seems fishy to me, but that is not my question.

It was proposed that we change our code so that if the origin meets our precondition that we return `*` instead of echoing the origin in the response.

My question is whether we open a potential security vulnerability by returning `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` to origins that match our preconditions. I would hope that browsers check the access control headers with every request. If so, I am not overly concerned. If not, I can imagine an attacker running an untrusted web site taking advantage of browsers that have previously received a `*` for a trusted origin.

I have read the [OWASP article on scrutinizing CORS headers](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/CORS_OriginHeaderScrutiny). The article does not reflect any of my concerns, which is reassuring; however, I wanted to inquire of the community before pressing forward.